# Adding scrollbar to an element if the content is more than what fits the viewport height

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css, css-position

I have a 2 column layout which uses flexbox. The navbar on top is sticky and so is the sidebar on left. I would like to add a scrollbar on the left sidebar if the content exceeds the viewport height. From what I have tried so far, I don't think this is possible without explicitly setting a height or max-height on it or using javascript. The problem with setting a height or max-height is that since I don't know how much content might be inside that sidebar, I don't want to explicitly set a value. If I use "fit-content" or "100%", that does not seem to activate the scrollbar[image]

Is it possible to achieve the scrollbar on the sticky sidebar with CSS alone ? Here's the code with my scenario :-

https://play.tailwindcss.com/p4xSQfZBRY

Comment: What's the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" CSS and HTML to reproduce your problem, and layout? To be clear, that code must be in your question (though a link to a live demo, [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), [Codepen](https://codepen.io), is a welcome bonus); please [edit] your question to include the (*minimal*) code.

Comment: You should set a max-height and `overflow-y: auto;`

Comment: Yes but the max height needs to be calculated with javascript to see how much of the sidebar fits into the viewport